# 2005 Kia Sedona sensor question

Tags: ignition, sensor, kia

This might be a silly question but do I need dielectric grease to install an ignition failure sensor where it mounts on to the thermostat housing assembly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What vehicle are you working on? Year/Model/Engine?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 2005 Kia Sedona 3.5L V6.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't, but it's a good idea anyways. The sensor connector should have a gasket on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: old sensor]

Here's a picture of the bottom of the old sensor. I thought it sat flush on the thermostat housing, but it's actually mounted on two posts above the housing. In any case, RPM gauge works now.